# php iconv translit for removing accents: not working with magento manufacture logo's

Tags: php, magento

I would like to replace some char assent which is not working what i am excepting for magento manufacture logo which is displaying on product attribute . 
Here is my code on manufacture_center.phtml where i am writing function for clearing unwanted special char which is working fine for removing special char  but not for the char like "â, é " i need to replace this with "a , e "  :

```
function manu_title_clean($text,$strict = false) {
$text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// replace non letter or digits by -
$text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);

// trim
$text = trim($text, '-');
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_GB.utf8');
// transliterate
if (function_exists('iconv')) {
   $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
}

// lowercase
$text = strtolower($text); 
// remove unwanted characters
$text = preg_replace('~[^-\w.]+~', '', $text);
if (empty($text)) {
   return 'empty_$';
}
if ($strict) {
    $text = str_replace(".", "_", $text);
}
return $text;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample text for which iconv()'s //TRANSLIT isn't working correctly? I used the original examples in your question ("â, é "), and it gets transliterated just fine. See http://ideone.com/ADEoAY

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by

```
function manu_title_clean($text,$strict,$str = false) {
$text = preg_replace('~[^\\pL\d.]+~u', '-', $text);
// trim
$text = trim($text, '-');
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_GB.utf8');
$unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                        'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                        'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                        'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
   $str = strtr( $text, $unwanted_array );
   $text = strtolower($str);
   $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w.]+~', '', $text);
   if (empty($text)) {
   return 'empty_$';
    }
   if ($strict) {
    $text = str_replace(".", "_", $text);
    }
    return $text;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The result seems to depend on the version of iconv (with the one in libc6 2.24 it stopped working).